# Creating arbitrary sized blank pngs/jpegs

Tags: image

I want to create arbitrary sized pngs and jpeg images of a single block colour at a specified x,y size, however I do not want to do this by generating a raw image in memory and encoding/compressing it due to potential memory requirements.

How would this be done?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I dont have to use any in particular for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to create an arbitrarly large PNG image on the fly, writing it to a stream (file, network or whatever) without having it created in memory, you can use -in Java- this [PNJG](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library (disclaimer, I wrote it). For example, this generates a black RGB8 image:

```
PngWriter png = FileHelper.createPngWriter(
     new File(filename), 
     new ImageInfo(cols, rows,  8, false),false);
ImageLine iline = new ImageLine(png.imgInfo);
for (int j = 0; j < cols ; j++) 
  ImageLineHelper.setPixelRGB8(iline, j, 0);
for (int row=0;row<rows; row++) {
  iline.setRown(row);
  png.writeRow(iline);
}
png.end();
```

Comment: Interesting, Ill try it out =]

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own generator.  Pseudo-code for a PNG generator is:

```
write_png_header(width,height);
gzip_scanline(width,colour);
for(y=1; y<height; y++) { // scanline 0 already written
  write_type_copy_previous();
  gzip_zero_delta(width);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what language you're using, or what your use case is, but I use the `convert` program from the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite to do this:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:transparent missing_normal.png
```

If you're creating images for a browser you could just create a single 1x1 image, then use the width and height attributes to let the browser scale it for you.

Comment: Nopa good suggestion but it preallocates the necessary space in memory, so for very big images it wouldnt be very nice =(

Comment: Doing some testing on cygwin, convert's memory usage is stable. It used no more memory for a 100000x100000 image than it did for a  10000x100000 image. Smaller images were created faster than I could see the memory usage.

Comment: hmmm, well I tried a 19k by 19k and my computer ground to a halt, I had to close the program and then it was almost 20 minutes before everythign started responding correctly again